# How to solve a multiple regression with country and sectorial dummies + third difference euqation? Need help for my master thesis!

Tags: multiple-regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I'm currently writing my master thesis about the topic

**"How do firms respond to rising cost of carbon - an analysis from the EU Emissions Trading System (EU ETS)?"**

In general, research on the EU ETS is always about whether the introduction of this policy instrument has led to a reduction in emissions. For my case, I specifically want to study the effect of the EU ETS from 2018 and compare it with the period 2013-2017. For this purpose, I found a scientific paper by [Abrell, Ndoye Faye and Zachmann (2011)](https://www.bruegel.org/wp-content/uploads/imported/publications/WP_2011_08_ETS_01.pdf), which uses a multiple regression with fixed effects to estimate and compare the effect of the EU ETS during the periods 2005-2006 and 2007-2008. Thus, the ultimate goal is to provide an indication of the extent to which companies reduced or increased their emissions during the 2007-2008 period compared to the 2005-2006 period.

$$ y_{it}= a_0+a_1d_{it}+a_2cv_{it}^1+a_3cv_{it}^2+\epsilon_{it} $$

where:

- $t$ = 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008
- $i$ and $t$ are respectively company and year index
- $y_{it}$ is the log value of verified emissions
- $d_{it}$ is a time dummy
- $cv_{it}^1$ is a set of control variables: turnover and labour in log values
- $cv_{it}^2$ is a second set of control variables: sectoral and country dummies
- $\epsilon_{it}$ is the error term which can be decomposed into a time variant $u_{it}$  and a firm specific effect $\eta_i$

I would like to use this scientific approach in my master thesis, because the data needed for this is publicly available and there are no problems in data collection. The data set is a **panel data set** (EUTL data set), which consists of all installations regulated under the EU ETS and their emissions from 2008-2021 . In addition, I have the control variables turnover and labour for each installation.

However, I struggle to understand and apply the statistical approach of Abrell, Ndoye Faye and Zachmann. In principle, I understand how to perform **multiple regression**, but I do not understand what is meant by **sectorial or country dummies**. Are sectorial/country dummies = sectorial/country fixed effects? If so, what are fixed effects in general and are they already present in my data set or do I need to add them somehow?

The parameter $a_1$ in the regression equation above is the parameter that describes my effect?

In addition, the researchers mention a third difference equation in their paper.

$$\triangle^3y_i = a_1+a_2\triangle^3cv_i^1+a_3\triangle^3cv_i^2+\triangle u_i$$

In the equation, $\triangle$ is the difference operator. The interesting parameter is $a_1$ which captures the change of behaviour in emissions by the firm from the first (2005-2006) to the second phase (2007-2008).

- Why do they list the third difference equation? Do I need this to arrive at my results?

Comment: Yes, the dummies are fixed-effects. This is just a series of dummy variables that are zero unless the observation is in that group, then they are one. There is something confusing here, though. If they are differencing the data, any country/sectoral dummies would not only be unnecessary but would be impossible to include. Only time-varying variables can remain in differenced models.